# TomEE 8 JDK level

Tags: apache-tomee

I am trying to find out what is the latest JDK level supported by TomEE 8 or 9. Specifically if JDK 15 will work. The [install documentation](https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-8.0/docs/installing-tomee.html) says only Java 6 or 7 are supported. That seems a bit too old.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The JDK compatibility and support of TomEE is not well documented. The "java compatibility" note in the official documentation is outdated. The Java versions mentioned in the install documentation are an obsolete minimum requirement - propably a copy & paste thingy.</s>

Here is what is known:

- TomEE 8.0.9 definitely supports JDK 8, JDK 11, JDK 17
- From a short stackoverflow research, for some users JDK 14 or JDK 15 also worked
- TomEE 9.x does only support the Jakarta namespace (Jakarta EE 8, Jakarta EE 9.x)

Watch the [Release Notes](https://tomee.apache.org/download.html) for updates.

Comment: TomEE 8.0.9 should support JDK 17 - at least we did some TCK runs with it  - latest release notes contain the hints.

Comment: Yes, you are right. TomEE has been updated since and my information was outdated. I updated everything.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-8.0/docs/java-compatibility.html) page only JDK 8 is supported by TomEE 8.